# Derivation of KLT relations

Tags: string-theory, integration, complex-numbers, analyticity

The KLT relations (Kawai, Lewellen, Tye) relate a closed string amplitude to a product of open ones. While I get the physics behind this I don't really understand the derivation in the original paper (see https://doi.org/10.1016/0550-3213(86)90362-7 ). Especially I don't understand the contour deformations starting around eq. (3.4) and following. I'd be glad if someone could either explain that a bit more in detail.

Comment: The paper is freely available in the KEK library: http://ccdb5fs.kek.jp/cgi-bin/img/allpdf?198511415 - And for the OP: could you please be more specific about what you don't understand? The paper is supposed to be self-explanatory and you surely don't want anyone to write a *longer* version of that paper here.

Comment: @Lubos: Thanks for the link. What I'm interested in is specifically the derivation of the phase factor (3.8). They do this by considering branch cuts of the integrand as they explain *in words* before. But just from those words I can't reconstruct precisely what they do. I tried to rederive their phase factor but then I don't see how they do it and moreover I can't reproduce figure 2 which is not in the KEK version unfortunately.

Comment: Dear Friendly Helper, the figures are at the end of the scanned PDF document.

Answer (score 3):

The specific question you are asking is unclear to me.  But I would like to point out to you a useful reference.  The KLT relations were originally derived in string theory, but in 2010-11, Thomas Sondergaard and colleagues at the Niels Bohr Institute found a purely field-theoretic proof based on new ideas in the theory of scattering amplitudes.  This proof is algebraic and does not make use of contour deformations.  It is also less specialized, in that it does not require the equipment of string theory.

Sondergaard wrote a nice review paper covering the KLT derivation and the new field-theoretic derivation. It is published in Advances in High Energy Physics, but you can find it more easily at https://arxiv.org/abs/1106.0033. You will find all of the original references there. This paper also introduces the Bern-Carrasco-Johanssen (BCJ) representation of gravity amplitudes, which is an important step beyond KLT.